# Linux File Names converted to blank rect after running sudo fc-cache -f -v

Tags: fonts, directory, 18.10, ubuntu-font-family

I'm beginner in Linux.

I have downloaded some fonts from net and I made some mistake to rebuild Ubuntu by these fonts. So I copied them to .fonts folder in home directory. After that I run this command and all files and folders names are converted to blank rects as showed in bellow:

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

How could I repair Ubuntu?
Currently I have these fonts in mentioned folder and I could not remove them:

```
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/Ubuntu-MI.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/Ubuntu-B.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/Ubuntu-L.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/Ubuntu-BI.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/Ubuntu-M.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/Ubuntu-RI.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/Ubuntu-LI.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/UbuntuMono-BI.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/UbuntuMono-RI.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/Ubuntu-Th.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/UbuntuMono-R.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/UbuntuMono-B.ttf': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/ai-station/.fonts/Ubuntu-C.ttf': Permission denied
```

[image: File and folders and terminal]

Comment: If you don't have permissions to the folder, use `sudo` to elevate your permissions and give you access to the directory where you get *permission denied* errors.  If the files were added in a home directory; I'd just remove them, (doing it in a text terminal having logged out of gui), re-run `fc-cache` (rebuild font info cache index) from a terminal, then re-login into gui.  Please note Ubuntu 18.10 is now EOL & off-topic on this site because of EOL status. You should release-upgrade to 19.04 ASAP.

Comment: ps:  If you don't like release-upgrading every 6-9 months, stick to LTS or long-term-releases, as standard releases like 18.10 require regular release-upgrades.

Comment: @guiverc I'm root so I have enough permission to run all commands?

Comment: Run that command in text terminal in my user account? It's possible to guide me by more details?

Comment: And how could I run commands out of GUI ?

Comment: You can do that after pressing Ctrl + Alt + F3 (or F4, F5...). You get back to your GUI by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F2.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was solved by your guidance.

Comment: @guiverc Please write your answer as a new solution or post in order to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have permissions to the folder, use `sudo` to elevate your permissions and give you access to the directory where you get permission denied errors.

If the [*font*] files were added in a home directory; I'd just remove them.

Please note I'd not try and do it in the difficult-to-read gui, instead logout [of gui] and but switch to terminal (ctrl+alt+F4 etc), re-run `fc-cache` (*rebuild font info cache index*), then re-login into gui. I would expect gui to look normal at this login :)

*Please note Ubuntu 18.10 is now EOL & off-topic on this site because of EOL status. You should release-upgrade to 19.04 ASAP*